# Texture Mapping to procedurally generated geometry

Tags: opengl, c++, directx, algorithm, vulkan

How can I calculate texture coordinates of such geometry?

The angle shown in the image (89.90 degree) may vary, therefore the geometry figure is changing and is not always such uniform.(maybe like geometry in the bottom of image) and red dots are generated procedurally depends on degree of smoothness given.

[image]

Comment: What is your definition of properly ? Does the texture "quads" map to the squew quads of the surfaces, does the numbers needs to be always unstretch or not ? You should in your example picture display how the result has to be before we can give a solution.

Comment: The main objective of my question is , how can I calculate texture coordinates procedurally generated mesh? which Techniques of UV mapping used in such situations that mesh generated procedurally ?

Comment: This is a far too broad question for SO. It is not because the position are procedural that the UVs have too sometimes, or a simple function to map a position to a texcoord can be enough. Unless you seek a specific result you can explain, it is not possible to provide an answer.

Comment: I edited the post, tried to give best objective of my problem

Comment: Sounds tricky. Why don't you instead use the vertex output position in screen space as UV (ie. a totally homogenous -1...1 space, that you fix to 0...1) and instead re-paint the texture (the boxes, whatever) accoringly, in advance? I guess you want them to be slightly offseted. This ofc requires a shader, and your mesh vertexes must sit within -1...1. This will produce better outlines for the boxes, which you cannot otherwise control (since the mesh lacks vertexes for the inner corner points). Also not that the GPU paints in any order.

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural Why did you tag OpenGL, DirectX, and Vulkan? Do you have an actual implementation in mind for this question? Have you tried any solutions that haven't worked for you yet? As it stands your question is a little too broad.

Comment: yes I have an actual implementation in opengl